# How to calculate the L3 cache miss rate using the perf cli tool?

Tags: linux, caching, cpu, perf, cpu-cache

Is there any way to calculate the LLC cache miss rate by the perf tool in Linux?

My perf output gives me the following command for the LLC cache:

LLC load misses, LLC loads, LLC stores, LLC store misses, and LLC prefetch misses.

Is there any way that, using these metrics, I could calculate the LLC cache miss rate of my application?

Also, using Perf, would it be possible to monitor these metrics all the execution and plot a chart? This will help me to monitor the program hot spots and analyze it better.